# Don't Unplug HDMI Cable with Equipment On?

Tags: hdmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Should I turn off my PC when plug/unplug external display?](https://superuser.com/questions/333874/should-i-turn-off-my-pc-when-plug-unplug-external-display)

I know there was the old saying that with VGA cables you never unplug them while the computer and/or monitor is turned on. I know that wasn't so much the case as equipment improved. Recently I upgraded from VGA to HDMI and I saw this in the paper work of the HDMI cable:

> Warning Card
>
> Please switch off all hardware devices (TV, Blu-Ray, PS3, Computer, etc.) prior to connecting or disconnecting the enclosed cable.

While it is probably the best to do that will I damage equipment if I unplug the cable with equipment turned on?

Comment: @Canha - Thanks for the link. That does answer my question. Did not see it when searching earlier.

Comment: No worries, sometimes it happens!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/440959/is-hdmi-hot-pluggable